# Angularjs & jQuery click event is not firing

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a tag dynamically and adding click event in Angularjs. but click event is not firing. I'm trying different types still click event is not firing.

```
  var optionShow = $("<a class='scenarioShow optionShow' ng-click='showOptions()'></a>").text('+Show').addClass(action.Name);
                                   parentDivTag.append(optionShow);

or click='showOptions()'


  $rootScope.showOptions = function () {
                   alert('opt1');
               }
               function showOptions() {
                   alert('opt');
               }

               $(".optionShow").on("click", function () {
                   alert('on');
               });
```

IE ViewSource:

```
<a class="scenarioShow optionShow CreateAd" ng-click="showOptions()">+Show</a>
or
<a class="scenarioShow optionShow CreateAd" click="showOptions()">+Show</a>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jquery and angular? Angular can do all the .on functionality, why make a mess with jquery? Also the correct attribute is `onclick` not `click`. And you shouldn't do this since you're binding an event listener with jqeury.

Comment: I had to use both in my logic for other scenario. Above code is just sample.

Comment: I don't see why this code wouldn't work. Make jsfiddle (or similar) with full example, showing that this logic isn't working. Or you could check your console for errors, for example something as trivial as improper order of script loading.